# How to create folder in favorites in windows 7

Tags: java, windows

How to add folder in favorites on windows 7 ?

I am developing desktop application I want add folder in favorites bar. how can implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get favorite folder path, you need to access RegistryKey and then you can create sub folders in that directory. The following C# code will create sub folders in favorite folder.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rKey = Microsoft.Win32Registry.CurrentUser;
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = rKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders",
true); 
string favoriteFolderPath = key.GetValue("Favorites").ToString();
string myFolder           = "MyFolder";
myFolder                  = Path.Combine(favoriteFolderPath, myFolder);

try
{
    // If the directory doesn't exist, create it.
    if (!Directory.Exists(myFolder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(myFolder);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
  //Could not create Directory
}
```

Comment: I want create folder shortcut in favorites like DropBox

Answer (score 0):

With JNA, it's easy to get a *Windows Special Folder* path.

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Shell32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.ShlObj;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;


// https://github.com/twall/jna#readme
//    you need 2 jars : jna-3.5.1.jar and platform-3.5.1.jar

public class GetFolderPathDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] pszPath = new char[WinDef.MAX_PATH];
    Shell32.INSTANCE.SHGetFolderPath(null,
      ShlObj.CSIDL_FAVORITES, null, ShlObj.SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT,
      pszPath);
    System.out.println(Native.toString(pszPath));
  }
}
```

Others [special folders](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/ShlObj.html)

Comment: I want create folder shortcut in favorites like DropBox